# jquery serialize with not selector

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-selectors

I've tried to use jquery serialize (*$.serialize()*) with *not* selector without success.
I have a table into a form and I want exclude it before serialize.

This is the code:

```
$("#id_form").not("#id_table").serialize();
```

This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfreL84w/embedded/result/) for explain the problem

Comment: Only forms can be serialized.

Comment: i tried with `$("#id_form").not("#id_table").html()` but it gives table html also. Any one have idea?

Comment: same thing happens if we replace `table` with `ul` & `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fork of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw39o00d/) using this solution

```
$("#test :input").not($("#tab1 :input")).serialize();
```

I think this is the better way

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `.clone()` of your `form` and just delete the `table` then you can use that to serialize:

```
var $clone =$("#id_form").clone();

$clone.find('table').remove();

var $frm = $clone.serialize();  // <-----here
```

<sub>Note: I am on mobile and unable to check fiddle.</sub>

Comment: I think it's the only viable solution, you know if this is performance-killer?

Comment: @Jai  `$("#id_form").not("#id_table").serialize();` not working. do have any idea?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi the code works, but I need to know something about performance :) You need to change ID_FORM and TABLE before try it

Comment: @Jai i have tried all that thing also not selected. :)

Comment: @Jai `$("#id_form").not("#id_table").html()` gives table html also.

Answer (score 1):

To filter only the inputs not belonging to the table you can use:

```
$("#id_form :input").filter(function() {
  return ($('#id_table').find($(this)).length == 0);
}).serialize();
```

Another solution is:

```
$("#id_form :input").not($('#id_table :input')).serialize();
```

A possible workaround to simplify the all task is to create an own filter:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
   inputNotInTable: function(ele) {
      var obj = $(ele);
       return obj.is(':input') == true && obj.closest('#tab1').length == 0;
   }
});

$("#test :inputNotInTable").serialize();
```

Comment: `$("#id_form").not("#id_table").serialize();` not working. do have any idea?

Comment: @gaemaf thanks, I need to know if this is ok with performance

Comment: @user2940867 I added another approach

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I found what you looked for

Comment: @gaemaf yes but why it can not exclude whole table. As you do select only input elements from table.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi because inputs are children of form but some of them are also children of table. A possible workaround is to create another filter like : $("#test :inputNotInTable")